# unable to save values in database with http post and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to write a PHP code used to save temperature data and timestamp in a database and show the value in a table. The temperature data is sent to database by using an http post.

here the code:

index.php (display the table)

```
<?php

include("connect.php");     

$link=Connection();

$sql="SELECT * FROM `temptrac_temp` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC";

$result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);

/* determine number of rows result set */
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Arduino thermometer control panel</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css?v=1.0">

</head>


<body>

<div class="container">

    <p>Temperature Arduino checker</p>

    <p>The temperature is:</p>  

    <table class="normal" border="2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Temperature&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Timestamp&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Status&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>

    <?php 
        if($result!==FALSE){


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {



                if($row["temp"] <= 8){

                    printf("<tr><td>&nbsp;%s</td><td>&nbsp;%s&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;Ok!&nbsp;</td></tr>", 
                        $row["temp"], $row["timestamp"]);
                }

                if($row["temp"] > 8){

                    printf("<tr><td>&nbsp;%s</td><td>&nbsp;%s&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;Alert!&nbsp;</td></tr>", 
                        $row["temp"], $row["timestamp"]);
                }

            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            mysqli_close($link);
        }else{

            printf("there is an error");

        }
    ?>

    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

connect.php (connection to mysql server)

```
<?php

function Connection(){


    /* php site version doesn't like so much "", prefer '' */
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'temptrac_temp', 'temptrac_temp2846', 'temptrac_temp');

    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    /* fuck maaan! check the function name return*/
    return $mysqli;

}
?>
```

add.php (write a new row in the database)

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$link = Connection();

$temp = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["temp"]);
//$lat =$_POST["lat"];
//$lng =$_POST["lng"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO temptrac_temp (ID, temp, timestamp) VALUES (NULL, temp=?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param("d", $temp);


$stmt->execute();



//mysqli_query($link, $query);


$stmt->close();
$link->close();

header("Location: index.php");
exit();
?>
```

I'm doing http post with https://www.hurl.it/

In the page response I see always (empty) instead to see the code of the index page like the connection is not closed.

I was able to write a new row in the database only one time, so is like sometimes work some other no.... that's weird.

> header("Location: index.php");

is the last line and is followed by

> exit();

so all the procedure should works.

here the screenshot of the http post

[image]

[image]

To prevent SQL Injection I followed this video https://youtu.be/sJdWuPHKRRY?t=11m1s. Is not clear to me how to use the bind function. here I see "uid=?" and not only "?". How to include my $temp variable that is dynamic in my sql query in a proper way?

tnx so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your insert query is wrong. It looks like you might have mixed up the syntax of insert and update. With inserts you will never do something like value = ?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO temptrac_temp (ID, temp, timestamp) VALUES (NULL, temp=?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
```

You would instead write the query like this.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO temptrac_temp (ID, temp, timestamp) VALUES (NULL, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
```

You can then do whatever you need to do to sub a real value in to the place of the ? in the query.

Comment: already tried like you told me. doesn't works. But is not clear for me how does this statement work. I see many version with =? or only ?, some with :name or :value.

Answer (score 0):

> **`Connection.php`  PAGE**

```
<?php

function Connection(){

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "demo";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

return $conn;

}
?>
```

> **`add.php`  PAGE**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "demo";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";


$sql = "INSERT INTO temptrac_temp (ID, temp, timestamp) VALUES (NULL,'?',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}



header("Location: index.php");
$conn->close();

?>
```

> **`index.php` PAGE**

```
<?php

include("connection.php");     

$link=Connection();

$sql="SELECT * FROM `temptrac_temp` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC";

$result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);

/* determine number of rows result set */
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Arduino thermometer control panel</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css?v=1.0">

</head>


<body>

<div class="container">

    <p>Temperature Arduino checker</p>

    <p>The temperature is:</p>  

    <table class="normal" border="2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Temperature&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Timestamp&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Status&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>

    <?php 
        if($result!==FALSE){


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {



                if($row["temp"] <= 8){

                    printf("<tr><td>&nbsp;%s</td><td>&nbsp;%s&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;Ok!&nbsp;</td></tr>", 
                        $row["temp"], $row["timestamp"]);
                }

                if($row["temp"] > 8){

                    printf("<tr><td>&nbsp;%s</td><td>&nbsp;%s&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;Alert!&nbsp;</td></tr>", 
                        $row["temp"], $row["timestamp"]);
                }

            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            mysqli_close($link);
        }else{

            printf("there is an error");

        }
    ?>

    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> **OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: cool! did you try by making a page or there is a kind of PHP editor, debugger online?

Comment: bro i did on my local machine .. :)

Comment: super tnx! you are great.... anyway I still wonder why there is not yet a good PHP debugger online.

Comment: there normal many site . just google it. like :  `http://phpio.net/` , `http://phpfiddle.org/` , `http://www.writephponline.com/` , `https://www.codechef.com/ide` , `http://phptester.net/` , `http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/` , `http://codepad.org/`  .. etc

Comment: @AndreaMancini .. if Get the Ans Then Please .. Tick right to the Question and up the vote :) happy to help any time !!

Comment: now I'm trying but it store always 0 as temperature. If I write `?` instead of '?' It output <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in 
<b>/home/temptrac/public_html/add.php</b> on line 
<b>14</b>
<br />

Comment: @AndreaMancini . its datatype is varchar in database ... so we have to use  `' ? '` this.. quotes.

Comment: @AndreaMancini  .. You want to store dynamic value in `temp` then you have to take the value from `post` or `get` and use as `$_GET["temp"]` or `$_POST["temp"]` in the place of  `$sql = "INSERT INTO temptrac_temp (ID,temp, timestamp) VALUES (NULL,$_GET["temp"],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");
$SQL= "INSERT INTO tabl1(reading,cost)VALUES(".$_GET["reading"].",".$_GET["cost"].")";
mysqli_query($dbh,$SQL);
header("Location: review_data.php");

?>
```

Read this script to add data into server. Hope it helps. Please let me known if any query.